# Load jquery without script tag

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I'm working on a script in Adobe Illustrator using Javascript. For long winded reasons I'm trying to avoid Extendscript, even though its very useful.

Is it possible to load the jquery library without using the  tag which for obvious reasons I cannot use as I'm working in Illustrator
Thanks
Bob

Comment: why do you want to use jquery in graphics design at the first place ?

Comment: We need to load external dataset from servers that will generate graphs. But also need to leave the door open to port the script to a browser at a later date so the less extendscript the better. Shame as I find it more user friendly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copy the jquery library and put it into your document above all your other code.

Comment: Yes, I suppose that's pretty obvious really. Although I was hoping there might be a way that meant I didn't have to wade through the library before getting to the code I'm working on.

Comment: No, I doubt there us another way without using HTML specific commands, looks like you'll have to wade through that library every time. Sorry.